# Why is there no UNIQUE constraint on parent ID of one-to-one relationship?

Tags: mysql

I was just about to create my database as I realized that I'm not sure how to map one-to-many or one-to-one relations. Therefore I took MySQL Workbench and created this simple example:

[image]

MySQL Workbench shows here the one-to-one relation between `A` and `C` as well as the one-to-many relation between `A` and `B`.

But exporting these tables as `.sql` file gives me this:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `reveng_me`.`A`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `reveng_me`.`A` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `reveng_me`.`B`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `reveng_me`.`B` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `A_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_B_A1_idx` (`A_id` ASC),      
  CONSTRAINT `fk_B_A1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`A_id`)
    REFERENCES `reveng_me`.`A` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `reveng_me`.`C`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `reveng_me`.`C` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `A_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_C_A1_idx` (`A_id` ASC),      
  CONSTRAINT `fk_C_A1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`A_id`)
    REFERENCES `reveng_me`.`A` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I can't see a difference between `B` and `C`. Shouldn't there be a `UNIQUE` constraint on `FOREIGN KEY ('A_id')` or something else that hinders me from adding more `A` IDs to `C`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is actually no such thing in MySQL. A 1-1 relation isn't different from a 1-n relation in the database scheme. Some RDBMS' allow for CHECK constrains to do this, but in MySQL the CHECK is merely implemented to complete the SQL standard. You can however create an unique index that's being referenced by the other table. This is probably what you want.

Comment: It's interesting that MySQL Workbench does visualize it differently despite it's actually the very same. But okay, that's good to know. I thought I was doing something wrong here ..

Comment: @StefanFalk You might want to look at some examples here http://www.mkyong.com/mysql/how-to-define-one-to-one-relationship-in-mysql/

Comment: To be honest I just switched to PostgreSQL but used the MySQL Workbench for the visualization part ^^. In doing so I noticed that the generated code looks like in my question and I was wondering what I could have done wrong. But thanks, the link looks like worth a look!

Comment: @StefanFalk Postgres should be able to do this with a CHECK constraint. One-to-one relations are not *that* common since the tables can usually be merged into one.